# webdriver-manager start command won't work if changes the directory structure

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the protractor tool and I am facing one issue related to chromedriver.
I have installed protractor locally using the command. `npm install protractor`
Corresponding protractor package added to "node_modules" folder. .[protractor installed with some version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZaOB.png)

I have update the webdriver-manager using the command.
`webdriver-manager update`.

webdriver-manager has been updated,Corresponding "update-config.json" updated with downloaded version of chromedriver. .[Selenuim folder inside webdriver-manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S69JB.png)

Eg.

```
chrome":{"last":"D:\\Html5EditorTestautomationRepo_local\\
html5-editor-testautomation_8April\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\
webdriver-manager\\selenium\\chromedriver_2.46.exe"
```

[updateConfig file upadte with hardcoded path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCO0U.png)

Now start up a webdriver-manager with cmd:
`webdriver-manager start`
It will start the webdriver-manager server.

Same project I have copied to other folder structure and deleted previous project folder.
Then trying to start the server again with same command.
but this time got the error saying chromedriver_2.46.exe could not found at particular path.

I don't want to update web driver-manager again.
since it hard coded path, It will fail.Even I am not able to give the my project other user.

So without updating web driver-manager how to solve this?????

Comment: I tried to move the node_modules folder to other folders after executing `webdriver-manager update`. But `webdriver-manager start` worked well in new folder.  And after search `update-config.json` in whole package `protractor/node_modules/
webdriver-manager`, `webdriver-manager start` won't to get the driver binary path from `update-config.json`,  it calculated the path dynamically.

Comment: Show the whole cmd output of `webdriver-manager start` in your box.